# Java Binary Trees/Visitor Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, binary-tree

So I can really get this I was wondering if anyone could help me out, the object of this program is to use the visitor pattern to generate a list of strings from the name of people in a given binary tree, if not really sure how to go about using an append function to do so. How would I append the person with its parents?

```
import tester.Tester;

//Representation for an ancestor tree
interface IAT {
    <R> R accept(IATVisitor<R> visitor);

    //Append two lists
    IList<String> append(IList<String> l);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Unknown person
class Unknown implements IAT {
    Unknown() {
    }
    public <R> R accept(IATVisitor<R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitUnknown(this);
    }
    //append two an unknown
    public IList<String> append(IList<String> l) {
        return l;
    }

}    
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Representation for a person
class Person implements IAT {
    String name;
    int yob;
    boolean isMale;
    IAT mom;
    IAT dad;
    //Constructor
    Person(String name, int yob, boolean isMale, IAT mom, IAT dad) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yob = yob;
        this.isMale = isMale;
        this.mom = mom;
        this.dad = dad;
    }
    public <R> R accept(IATVisitor<R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitPerson(this);
    }
    //append parent and children of tree
    public IList<String> append(IList<String> l) {
        //
    }

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IATVisitor<R> {
    R visitUnknown(Unknown u);
    R visitPerson(Person p);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//IAT Visitor that returns a list of the names of all people
class IATVisitGetNames implements IATVisitor<IList<String>> {
    public IList<String> visitUnknown(Unknown u) {
        return new MT<String>();
    }
    public IList<String> visitPerson(Person p) {
        return new Cons<String>(p.name, new MT<String>());
    }
}

//Examples
class ExamplesIATV {
    //persons
    Unknown a = new Unknown();
    Person ralph = new Person("Ralph", 1995, true, a, a);
    Person kevin = new Person("Kevin", 1994, true, a , a);
    Person julia = new Person("Julia", 1991, false, ralph, a);
    Person lily = new Person("Lily", 1990, false, kevin, julia);
    Person who = new Person("?", 1738, false, lily, a);

    //Visitor
    IATVisitor<IList<String>> byName = new IATVisitGetNames(); 


    //test Vistior
    boolean testGetNames(Tester t) {
        return 
                t.checkExpect(who.accept(byName), new MT<String>());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean by 'append the person with its parents'. Given the test data in your example, what would you want the output of, say, `who.append(MT<String>())` to be?

Answer (score 1):

First - you want collect all names from tree. You need traversal function, for example:

```
public void traverse(Node root) {
   //do somesing with node
   System.out.println(root.value);
   if (root.left != null) {
      traverse(root.left);
   }
   if (root.right != null) {
      traverse(root.right);
   }
}
```

Second - you want to use Visitor pattern. How wikipedia says:

> Visitor - is a way of separating an algorithm from an object structure
>   on which it operates.

So visitor is not suitable for travers/itereate logic. With visitor we can only incapsulate some logic on node:

```
public void traverseWithVisitor(Node root, IVisitor v) {
  root.accept(v);
  if (root.left != null) {
     traverseWithVisitor(root.left, v);
  }
  if (root.right != null) {
     traverseWithVisitor(root.right, v);
  }
}
```

Now incapsulate our collecting names logic in visitor:

```
class AggregateNamesVisitor implements IVisitor {

   public List<Integer> names = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public void visit(Node node) {
      names.add(node.value);
   }
}
```

We can use it like this:

```
AggregateNamesVisitor aggregateVisitor = new AggregateNamesVisitor();
traverseWithVisitor(root, aggregateVisitor);
aggregateVisitor.names.forEach(name -> System.out.print(" " + name));
```